# Jenkins :Sending Mail via python using win32

Tags: python, email, jenkins, winapi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1a8G.png)I am calling python script in jenkins to send email using win32, the script works perfectly when run from command window, but throws error when used in jenkins pipeline.

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook=win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail=outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To='abc@xyz.com'
mail.Subject="Test Mail"
mail.HTMLBody="Hiii, This is just a test mail."
mail.Send()
```

Error : IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)